# Not working - deploying node application on IIS (iisnode) - Getting back 403 error

Tags: node.js, express, iis, deployment, web-deployment

I have a node/express API project. I am trying to run this project through Internet Information Service (IIS). My current structure within IIS - Sites -> environment (website) -> project1 | project2 (node application here). I converted project2 to an application with the environment app pool name. I then create the app.

I try to hit my url but I get back a 403 forbidden error. I have given it all of the credentials. Unsure why this is happening.

Some resources I've been using - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0) [blog](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html)

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- 
      By default IIS will block requests going to the bin directory for security reasons. 
      We need to disable this since that's where Express has put the application entry point. 
    -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the www file is a node.js entry point -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <!--<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>


        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>


        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> -->

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="sendToNode">
        <match url="/*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const compression = require('compression')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer')
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const index = require('./routes/index')
const something1 = require('./routes/something1')
const something2 = require('./routes/something2')
const responseTime = require('response-time')

const app = express()
// const app = express.createServer()
const port = 3000

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8100',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
}



//added security
app.use(helmet())

// //set logger
// app.use(logger)

//cors options
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

// Mount express-sanitizer here
app.use(expressSanitizer()) // this line follows bodyParser() instantiations

//set static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../www')))

//Use response time
app.use(responseTime())

// set our default template engine to "ejs"
// which prevents the need for using file extensions
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//gzip compression
app.use(compression())

//add authorization request header
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.headers.authorization){
        return res.status(403).json({ error: 'No credentials sent!'});
    }
    // try {
    //     let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    //     var decoded = jwt.decode(token, 'your secret here');
    //     console.log(decoded, 'decoded')
    //   } catch (err) {
    //     console.log('err ', err.stack);
    //     return res.status(403).json({
    //       error: 'invalid token'
    //     });
    //   }
    next();
})

//set views for error and 404 pages
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use('/', index)
app.use('/something1/v1', something1)
app.use('/something2/v1', something2)

// app.listen(port, () => {
//     console.log('server started on port 3000')
// })

//run export NODE_ENV=production
//NODE_ENV=production node app.js

app.listen(process.env.port)
```

I have everything installed - (rewrite/node/iisnode) Just don't know how to set it up. Thanks

Comment: have you tried setting up simple hello world program instead of your complete app... with less of web.config... once it works you can take it forward, then you will get know exact root cause which is stoping you to run your app...

Comment: Yes I was able to get it working with using a website as the source rather than applications within that website. That is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I think the way you've setup the website in IIS is not quite right.

Sound like your IIS structure is like:

```
Sites
└─── environment
     └─── project1
     └─── project2
          |    app.js
          |    web.config
          |    ...
```

Where `environment` is a website, and each folder under it is probably a folder which has been converted to an `application`.

This seems to be a common mistake people are making because the hello world tutorial runs as an application under the `Default Web Site` (although I'm not sure why this is the case, but my guess is because it doesn't replace the default website which is easily accessible over port 80 on localhost). This isn't the best way to setup a new IISNode website.

**What you should do** is add a new site (right click `Sites` and choose `Add Website` from the context menu). Fill out the necessary details and point the `Physical path:` to where your `app.js` and `web.config` reside.

IISNode should handle the rest if you've setup the `web.config` right.

Good luck and let me know if I've made any wrong assumptions.

Comment: You are 100% correct. Is there a way to use that same IIS structure? Would this package help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain

Comment: Hmm it's not the sort of thing I have experience with. You want to be able to access your website via a subdomain? That's possible just using the method I described above... But maybe you should take a look at Reverse Proxying with IIS? You can then run your application as a normal Node process but get IIS to manage to connections to remote connections: https://serverfault.com/q/47537 Though I'm not sure if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix a similiar problem adding a *iisnode* tag.

The Web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="sendToNode">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
<iisnode
      watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;views\*.ejs" 
nodeProcessCommandLine="\program files\nodejs\node.exe" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I followed these tutorials to host my node.js apps:

[Harvey Williams Tutorial](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode) and [Scott Hanselman Tutorial](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx)