# 403 when trying to deploy a Node app to IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, windows-server

Inside this directory is my Node app: `/wwwroot/poldeb/internal_affairs_incident_reporter`

[image]

My app is running on port 8080.

In IIS, this is my configuration:

[image]

I can get to [www.poldeb.com](http://www.poldeb.com) fine because I have a static HTML page there, but when I try to get to [www.poldeb.com/IAIR](http://www.poldeb.com/IAIR) where my Node.js app should be running, I get a 403 error. How do I access my Node.JS app from this subdomain?

Comment: Look at this article, section with text 'I made a new AppPool just for node', don't think anything changed since it was written, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/installing-and-running-nodejs-applications-within-iis-on-windows-are-you-mad

Comment: @MZM i just installed iisnode 0.2.26 as a module but i don't see a difference

Comment: this question has been answer before, see this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984735/not-working-deploying-node-application-on-iis-iisnode-getting-back-403-err

Comment: What is "IAIR"? you can use failed request tracing to see details about 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got through this error by refactoring my IIS structure. I made IAIR its own website and gave it the subdomain `iair.poldeb.com`. Inside of IAIR, this was my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="sendToNode">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also had to give write access to the user `IIS_IUSRS` for the `internal_affairs_incident_reporter` directory.